# AWS - Throttling ELB HTTP Traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, throttling

I'm running a pretty standard LAMP stack on AWS.  ELB distributes traffic to a few EC2 Instances running the same application.

I have an issue where periodically I receive a huge spike in HTTP traffic from some of my customers. Is there a way (via WAF or something of this nature) to put in place throttling limits. Something akin to 'if IP X makes 1000 requests in 1 minute stop any further traffic from them for a period of time'?

Keep in mind it's not possible for me to know my customer's full range of IPs beforehand so a solution needs to be dynamic.

Any guidance on a best practice approach to this problem would be most gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Naturally AWS has a WAF, [with templates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-ddos-cross-service-WAF.html) containing [rate-based and other rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-wizard-create-rule).

Or you could put your favorite WAF in front of this.

Comment: This link is more helpful https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-get-started-rate-based-rules.html

Comment: Apparently in this space AWS has WAF and Shield Advanced products, and they duplicate explanation of rate-based rules. I don't know the products well enough to explain the difference.